# building and installing extensions during pip install -e

Tags: python, cmake, pip

I have a `setup.py` with a CMake extension:

```py
from setuptools.command.build_ext import build_ext


class CmakeExtension(build_ext):
    ...


if __name__ == "__main__":
    setup(
        ...
        cmdclass={
            "build_ext": CmakeExtension, # Build the C++ extension using cmake
        },
        ext_modules= [
            Extension('a', sources=[]),
            Extension('b', sources=[]), 
        ]
    )
```

building this using `python3 seutp.py bdist_wheel` or `python3 -m build . --wheel` works nicely - a wheel is created and it contains the relevant cmake object file.

However, `pip install -e .` fails to call the cmake procedure - leaving me with only the python files, without the critical shared object.

I can circumvent this by first building a wheel, and then installing it, but I have 2 issues with it:

1. the petty reason - I prefer a single command (`pip install` vs. `setup.py bdist_wheel && pip install`)
2. the main reason - I want my installation to be editable, and installing a wheel is not

The [docs](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/development_mode.html) say:

> The editable term is used to refer only to Python modules inside the package directories. Non-Python files, external (data) files, executable script files, binary extensions, headers and metadata may be exposed as a snapshot of the version they were at the moment of the installation.

Would that allow me to combine editable installation with the binary extension?